# Sometimes Menu expansion for each tool in tool menu won't expand

Tags: interface

I'm trying to select other extrude tools but it won't open the sub menus even if I just spam left or right clicks.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Press and hold left mouse? Restart blender?

Comment: lol. I didn't try 'holding'.... Thanks alot for helping a dummy like me xD